# Update .m3u8 playlist file for HTTP Live streaming?

Tags: http-live-streaming

I am converting MPEG-2 transportable format from incoming movie for live streaming which is not playable, then validate the .m3u8 file by using mediastreamvalidator, it says "WARNING: stream discontinuity detected without EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag". The conversion happen using FFMPEG, please help me what i am missing?

Sri

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this refers to PTS and PCR discontinuity. When a different streams are generated using fresh context - the PTS and PCR values might be completely off the sync. This can be a potential problem that throws *Warning* of discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

When using FFMPEG, you can rewrite the timestamps on the output files with the setpts option.