# MPEG-TS Segments HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, playlist, mpeg

I'm trying to interleave MPEG-TS segments but failing. One set of segments was actually captured using the built in camera in the laptop, then encoded using FFMPEG with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -er 4 -y -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -r 30 -i %s -isync -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -fflags +genpts -b 386k -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 386k -maxrate 386k -bufsize 386k -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -aspect 640:480
```

And the other one is an avi file that was encoded using the following command:

```
fmpeg -er 4 -y -f avi -s 640x480 -r 30 -i ./DSCF2021.AVI -vbsf dump_extra -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -fflags +genpts -b 386k -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 386k -maxrate 386k -bufsize 386k -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -aspect 640:480
```

Then the output is segmented into ts segments using an open source segmenter.

If both come from the same source (both from the camera) they work fine. However in this case, the second set of segments freeze. Time passes, but the video does not move..
So i think it's an encoding problem. So my question is, how should i change the ffmpeg command for this to work?

By interleave I mean, having a playlist with the first set of segments, and another playlist with the other set of segments, and having the client call one then the other (HTTP Live Streaming)

The ffprobe output of one of the first set of segments:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'live1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:09.76, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 281 kb/s
  Program 1 Service01
    Metadata:
      name            : Service01
      provider_name   : FFmpeg
    Stream #0.0[0x100]: Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.83 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x101]: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 111 kb/s
```

The ffprobe output of one of the second set of segments:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'ad1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:09.64, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 578 kb/s
  Program 1 Service01
    Metadata:
      name            : Service01
      provider_name   : FFmpeg
    Stream #0.0[0x100]: Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x101]: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 22 kb/s
```

Thank you,

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it should be ok. Can you show the ffprobe output from each stream?

Comment: Another possible solution could be to combine the captured video and the avi file into a single video before doing the encoding and segmenting.

Comment: @vipw Thank you for your reply. I can't combine them because the captured stream is live.. As for the ffprobe. I'll add it now

Comment: @user1069624 can you give me details of which software you use for segmenting? What refers to *segments using an open source segmenter*?

Comment: @DipanMehta Yes I'm using Carson Mcdonald's Live Segmenter. [HTTP Live Segmenter](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor)

Comment: @user1069624 Does it shows any warnings?

Comment: @user1069624 You can see that the streams are very different. You should try using the same framerate. The best solution is probably to read the v4l device with 25fps instead of 30. Also the bitrates are very different, but I'm guessing the fps is more likely to cause problems.

Comment: @DipanMehta no, no errors. And when both streams are coming from the camera, it works fine. The problem is when the streams are different. For example, one from the camera and one flv, also when 2 flv files that are different, it doesn't work. But if its the same flv, it works fine...

Comment: @vipw I tried setting -r 25 instead of 30, but i still get the same values! I get this message: "Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (60000/1001) -> 29.92 (359/12)"

Comment: @user1069624 Can you somehow change the v4l device to 25fps? You can have ffmpeg do the pull down to 25fps if you put the -r 25 AFTER the input file. When you put it before the input, it is a hint about the input file's framerate. Also, what's going on with your audio? You had it set as MP3 in the ffmpeg line, but it somehow is AAC in your outputs

Comment: @vipw Thank you, it worked, you were right about the frame rate, that was the problem.. I don't know what i was think putting it before the input file! About the audio yes sorry.. i played around in the middle and changed it to aac.. sorry about that! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

I have seen quite a few questions in the subject - See:

1. [HTTP Live Streaming MPEG TS segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417752/http-live-streaming-mpeg-ts-segment)  and
2. [Update .m3u8 playlist file for HTTP Live streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374533/update-m3u8-playlist-file-for-http-live-streaming)

I am not sure exact problem - but i think most people complain that when you mix content from both sources  are different then there is a freezing.

I think this situation may arise if PTS and/or PCR is discontinuous and the player is not recognizing this or flushing it. Probably, you can identify the sequence of Timestamps and see if that being fixed solves the problems.

Also, see 3.3.11.  of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07 : EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY

> The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag indicates an encoding discontinuity
> between the media segment that follows it and the one that preceded
> it.  The set of characteristics that MAY change is:
>
> o  file format
> o  number and type of tracks
> o  encoding parameters
> o  encoding sequence
> o  *timestamp sequence*

So a discontinuity flag in the playlist file might just help if the problem is any of the above. Please try some of this, and put more details. I guess, this will help lot of other people as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, unfortunately the Discontinuity tag didn't work for me.. the only thing that worked was changing the frame rate.. However I had this sequence problem before, where the screen would freeze if I'm playing segments out of order. I solved it by having a separate playlist for every new stream. So If I wanted to play segments 1,2,3 from stream x then segments 21,22 from stream y, I created a separate playlist with 21 and 22 alone. Thanks again!